# unChecked call to Class<T>

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, repository, entity, unchecked

```
public class UserHeaderRepository<TEntity>{

  private final CollectionReference collectionReference;

  private final Class<TEntity> entityClass;

  public static UserHeaderRepository getInstance()
  {          

     return new UserHeaderRepository(UserHeader.class);
  }

  public UserHeaderRepository ( Class < TEntity > entityClass ) {

    this.entityClass = entityClass;
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    this.collectionReference = db.collection("global_community");
 }
```

I don't know why I got the below error:

```
unchecked call to  UserHeaderRepository(Class<TEntity>)  row type 'as a member of raw type  '../appRepository/UserHeaderRepository'
```

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: *FYI:* Your static `getInstance()` method uses *raw* version of `UserHeaderRepository`. Don't do that. [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/5221149)

Comment: it got error here  "return new UserHeaderRepository(UserHeader.class)"

Comment: Is this a warning or an error? As @Adwait said in his answer it should be just a warning.

Answer (score 1):

You are [using raw types where you were supposed to use the parameterized type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it), change the `getInstance` method to this,

```
public static UserHeaderRepository<UserHeader> getInstance() {
    return new UserHeaderRepository<>(UserHeader.class);
}
```

Also it should not be an error it should be warning from the compiler.